# Integrating STB in Android programmatically

Tags: android, iptv

I'm developing an Android application in which according to the requirements I have to integrate IPTV. I have the IPTV portal url, mac address. But i don't know how to do it. Is it possible firstly to integrate it, if yes then how it can be done because I have never heard of it before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IPTV can mean different things to different people but it can help to maybe break it down into a couple of different types to answer your question:

- broadcast IPTV where the operators owns the IP network and provides the TV service as a managed service on their IP network. Basically it is TV broadcast which happens to be using an IP network for the service delivery.
- OTT Video or TV services where the service provider delivers their service over public internet.

Both types may provide live TV, catchup or recorded TV and Video on Demand services.

Note, these are not absolute definitions, but they can help this discussion.

If your use case if a very simple OTT service then you may simply have to integrate a player into your app and provide the Url to the OTT feed or channel.

If the service if a more complex OTT service then the server side will mostly likely provide API's for content menu, or electronic programs guide (EPG) and possibly some sort of recommendation service. You will need to work with the server side to integrate with these API's to 'fill' the menu screens you show to your user.

An IPTV service will be largely the same, although it is much more likely that it will not just be the simple case but one where you have multiple server side API's to integrate with.

Its is also worth being aware of the content security requirements for these types of services - OTT services typically will require DRM for any valuable content, so you need to make sure your device and player supports DRM (most do). You may also have to integrate your app into a subscriber management system API on the server side, so that the server can verify that a particular subscriber is entitled to the particular channel or movie they want to watch.

Finally, if your target is actually set top boxes or TV's rather than mobile and tablets, then there are actually STB's and TV's which are built using Android. In general there are two main approaches here:

- devices using Google's Android TV (https://www.android.com/tv/)
- devices built using the Android open source project (https://source.android.com/security/)

Both are in use and they have different characteristics and proponents - as a general rule ASOP is more open (unsurprisingly).

Comment: thanks a lot, it is a good information up here. And by IPTV i meant the first option you described.

Answer (score 0):

As your question You want to create an application that install on your **Android Box** and load your portal URL and do something like existing SetUpBox such as play video or ...

First you must add launcher permission to your application

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Then for disable access user to *Android Box Setting* you must enable **kiosk** mode to your application. If you want see Setting by your Administrator, you can define a code (like 2852) that when press this code show setting manually in your app.

You must have an Activity that contain **WebView** and load your portal URL in that. another suggestion is have a database in your application and store default Portal URL in that.

You must have another activity that contain player. It's a important to a SetUpBox that have a player for play **Live stream** and **VOD** stream. If you want to load Player Activity from your webpage please read [my question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002165/how-to-show-an-activity-with-javascript-code-in-webview).

And Finally its better that develop automatic download for new version in your application. Its help you to manage your client well.