# How to show an activity with JavaScript code in Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview

My application has a first activity that contains **Webview** and loads a simple page from the server in the beginning of the application.

Page code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn_foo"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a second activity that has a video player.

How can I **show/hide** the second activity via JavaScript in my webpage? For example, when I click on `btn_foo` (like VLC plugin in Firefox that can send commands to it via JavaScript).

Comment: You're looking for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks but with section...it seem the page contain webview function only

Comment: The link contains *exactly* what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do in your `onCreate`:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void doStuff(String param) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // start Video Activity here
            }
        });
    }
}

final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

/* enable JavaScript */
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

/* Register a new JavaScript interface called Android */
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");

/* load a web page */
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

In your loaded website, when the button is clicked, run

```
Android.doStuff("video1"); // calling the @JavascriptInterface method
```